# Android | Continuously update UI on receiving a push notification

Tags: android, user-interface, push-notification

I want to update my UI as soon as I receive the push notification, similarly how facebook updates its notification count.

What I have achieved:

1. I get the notification.
2. I save the value in the shared preferences. This is continuously updating, as soon as I get a new notification, my value in the shared preferences is updated. It is updated on onReceive method of the BroadcastReceiver.
3. I open the activity (UI), the first time it gets the value and is displayed correctly.

Problem:

I am in the activity (UI) and the notifications keep on coming, thus changing the value in the shared preferences. Now my UI is not updated until I move to another activity and come back. UI is created in onCreate method.

Question: How can I update my UI continuously as soon as the notification arrives, without moving away from or changing my current activity (UI).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you store a value in a shared preference than I suggest using OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html in the activity.

Answer (score 1):

While your method of storing the data is questionable, you can [register](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%28android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%29) an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. This will receive a callback when your preferences are changed. Note that it *must be an instance variable* and *not* an inner anonymous class.

```
private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        updateNotificationCount();
    }
};
```

You can register this as follows (assuming you're just using the default shared prefs file):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPrefs(context);
sharedPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
```

Comment: What do u suggest is a better way of storing data in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You could register your activity to the same broadcast as the class you have right now, using `sendOrderedBroadcast` you can specify the order your receivers will get the broadcasted message. Here you can put your Activity with a higher priority than the other class and

A) Update your shared preferences
B) update your textview

and then call to abortBroadcast, I'll give you a sample code:

The class that sends the broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("increase action");
intent.putExtra("new value");
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent,null);
```

Your activity

First you have to create a broadcastreceiver

```
private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //Do your work
       abortBroadcast();
  }
}
```

And then register it

```
IntentFilter filterSync = new IntentFilter();
filterSync.addAction("increase action");
filterSync.setPriority(100);
registerReceiver(myregister, filterSync);
```

Remember this, you have to register your `BroadcastReceiver`in your `onResume` method and unregister it in your `onPause` method.

Hope it helps